# If $A, B$ are real matrices with $AB=BA$, must $B\lvert_{E(\lambda_1, A)}$ have a real eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A, B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $AB=BA$. Assume that $A$ and $B$ have at least one real eigenvalue (not necessarily the same value). Then $A$ and $B$ share an eigenvector.

What I have:
Since $A$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, there exists a real eigenvector $v$ of $A$. This means for $v\in E(\lambda_1, A)$ we have $Av=\lambda_1 v$ and $BAv=ABv=\lambda_1 Bv$. Thus $Bv\in E(\lambda_1, A)$.

Let $v_1, v_2, ..., v_k$ be a basis of $E(\lambda_1, A)$. Since $Bv\in E(\lambda_1, A)$ for some $v$, we can write $Bv_i= c_{i1}v_1 + c_{i2}v_2 + ... + c_{ik}v_k$ where $1\leq i\leq k$ and $c_{ij}$ are real constants.

Now let $u\in E(\lambda_1, A)$ with $u=d_1 v_1 + d_2 v_2 +...+d_k v_k$. It follows that
\begin{align}
Bu & = B(d_1 v_1 + ... + d_k v_k) \\\\
 & = d_1 B v_1 + ... + d_k B v_k \\\\
 & = d_1 (c_{11}v_1 + c_{12}v_2 + ... + c_{1k}v_k) + ... + d_k(c_{k1}v_1 + c_{k2}v_2 + ... + c_{kk}v_k) \\\\
 & = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & d_2 & \dots & d_k
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} & \dots & c_{1k} \\\\
c_{21} & c_{22} & \dots & c_{2k} \\\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
c_{k1} & c_{k2} & \dots & c_{kk} \\\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\\\
v_2\\\\
\vdots \\\\
v_k\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

This is where I'm stuck. If I can show
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} & \dots & c_{1k} \\\\
c_{21} & c_{22} & \dots & c_{2k} \\\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
c_{k1} & c_{k2} & \dots & c_{kk} \\\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\\\
v_2\\\\
\vdots \\\\
v_k\\\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mu v_1\\\\
\mu v_2\\\\
\vdots \\\\
\mu v_k\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
for some real constant $\mu$, then I can write
\begin{align}
Bu & = d_1\mu v_1 + d_2\mu v_2 + ... + d_k\mu v_k\\\\
& = \mu(d_1v_1 + ... + d_kv_k)\\\\
& = \mu u\\\\
\end{align}
This would mean $u$ is an eigenvector of $B$, and since $u\in E(\lambda_1, A)$, it is also an eigenvector of $A$.

However, I am not sure how to go about this. Everything I have read either only works when the field is algebraically closed (i.e. $A,B: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$) or assumes $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable.

Basically, I am trying to figure out if $B\lvert_{E(\lambda_1, A)}$ must have at least one real eigenvalue when $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and is not necessarily diagonalizable.

Comment: As pointed, this is not true (it would be true though, if you allowed complex eigenvalues/eigenvectors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true.
Try $$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\cr}$$
Then $AB = BA$, and both $A$ and $B$ have real eigenvalue $1$ and complex eigenvalues $\pm i$, but they do not share a real eigenvector.